# Shopify - logic statements and CSS

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to change a css property in a Shopify liquid page using a logic statement?
Something like:

```
{% case template %}
{% when 'index' %}
#headlogo{display:none}
{% endcase %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put something like this in **theme.liquid**:

```
<head>
  ...

  {% case template %}
  {% when 'index' %}
    <style> 
      #headlogo { display:none }
    </style>
  {% endcase %} 
</head>
```

Or you could conditionally load stylesheets, [see here for an example](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/solved-conditional-statement-in-css-liquid-133552#comment-133673):

```
{% if template contains 'index' or template contains 'collection' %}
  {{ 'style.theme-dark.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% else %}
  {{ 'style.theme-light.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the `<body>` instead:

```
<body class="{% if customer %}customer-logged-in{% endif %} template-{{ template | replace: '.', ' ' | truncatewords: 1, '' | handle }}">
```

Then you can do:

```
.template-index #headlogo {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "if template" statements only on **Layouts**, **Templates** and **Snippets**.

Here better decision

theme.liquid or some Template, Snippet:

```
<div id="headlogo"{% if template == 'index' %} class="hide_logo"{% endif %}>
```

css

```
.hide_logo{
   display: none;
}
```